# Hernia repair with a mesh

Tags: exercise, surgery, hernia

I'm wondering if hernia repair with a mesh prevents the hernia from growing.

I'm imagining a sort of plaster being placed over the hernia but the hole still being there and growing.

Or is the mesh somehow preventing the weak spot from growing?

Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstand the mesh. It's not placed over the hernia externally. It's surgically implanted.

Comment: Why are people down voting the question?

Comment: @CareyGregory No, I know it's surgically implanted. But I'm saying that it's stitched over the hole but the hole itself is there. This makes me wonder if the hole in the tissue will continue expanding. You know?

Comment: See my comment above. It appears you didn't do basic research on your question before asking.

Comment: we're speaking parallel to each other.
You're saying that the mesh is "surgically implanted". I agree. Can the hole in the muscle continue to grow below the mesh?
P.S. I know it's implanted over the hole in the tissue. My question is regarding the tissue under the mesh.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfc-g7gFhzo

Answer (score 2):

Hernia has a chance of recurring. That's why they use mesh to strengthen the wall and prevent recurrence of hernia.

"The incidence of recurrent hernia after primary repair of a groin hernia varies from 1% in specialized centers to 30% in general surveys. During the premesh era, it was estimated that primary inguinal hernia repairs had a 10%–30% recurrence rate and that the rate was 35% for recurrent hernia repairs"

**Source:**

Recurrence after groin hernia repair-revisited

Sri VengadeshGopal AchuthanWarrier

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1743919113000873